# Residue of f$f(z)=\Gamma \left(\frac{z+1}{a} \right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, residue-calculus

How to find a residue of  \begin{align}
f(z)=\Gamma \left(\frac{z+1}{a} \right)
\end{align} 
for $a>0$.

I know that the Gamma function has poles for non-positive integers  so the polls happen at 
\begin{align}
z_n= -ka-1,  \ k=0,1,2,...
\end{align}

but no sure how to compute the residue.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757445/sum-of-gamma-function-residues?rq=1

Comment: @MyGlasses Very similar, but the computation of residue is not shown. :(

Comment: I hope that some user provide you a detailed answer. I believe that you need the same technique showed in Section 3 of a lecture notes from Cornell University searching in Google *residues of the gamma function*. After you can do a comparison with the output of the online calculator of Wolfram Alpha, when you type the input *residues Gamma((z+1)/a)*. Good luck.

Comment: @user243301  I hope this is not something very difficult?

Comment: @user243301 Bleh, who needs that ;-)

Comment: $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\sin(\pi z) = \pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$$

and more generally,

$$(x+a)\dots(x+2)(x+1)(x)\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+a+1)$$

Thus, to calculate the residue:

$$(x+a)\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma(x+a+1)}{(x+a-1)\dots(x+2)(x+1)(x)}\to(-1)^a/a!$$

As $x\to-a$.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, phone plus MathJax is pretty painful.

Comment: You are right with respect your comment below the question, thanks I've read your answer, +1.

Comment: @SimpleArt Does your approach work when $a$ is  any positive real number?

Comment: So how do you use $x \Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ on $\Gamma \left( \frac{z+1}{a} \right)$? How would the final answer look?

Comment: @Lisa the Gamma function only has poles on the negative integers, and for yours, you have to evaluate the limit:$$(z+1)\Gamma((z+1)/a$$so let $s=(z+1)/a$. And it follows from there.

Comment: @SimpleArt So, is the answer $ a \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ ???

Comment: @Lisa Yup :-)  Good job!